# Sharepoint Training

Tags: sharepoint

I need to learn Sharepoint, not so much admin functions, but usage/development.
Anyone know if Microsoft makes a free version, and if I need to learn .NET/C# or any other tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure you learn .NET (you're best off learning C# in my opinion)

After you have that down, sign up for a SharePoint boot camp. I just attended one from [Unitek](http://www.unitek.com/training/) and it was excellent.

It's not free, but they're usually about a week long and will get you up to speed much faster than self-teaching...and you'll be learning 'best practices' at the same time. Sharepoint is a technology that is easy to get lost in if you're not familiar with it.

Answer (score 1):

Free SharePoint Training from Microsoft:

http://www.microsoft.com/click/SharePointDeveloper/

Yes, you need to learn .NET/C#/ASP.NET. Others have done it, so can you! :-)

Comment: Is that hands on and allows for one to code and test or does it imply that one already has Sharepoint?

Comment: Virtual labs, webcasts, instructional videos, etc. I would also suggest training - check out the new training company run by Ted Pattison and Andrew Connell (can;t remember the company name offhand). Pattison's book "Inside Windows SharePoint Services" is often recommended as a first book. This will probably be updated soon for SharePoint Foundation (aka WSS 3.0+).

Comment: WSS is free. For software and tools, check out:
http://www.microsoft.com/web/websitespark/
You can get a pile of stuff for $100 :-)

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft offers a trimmed down version for free called Sharepoint Services 3.0, [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/sharepoint/default.aspx) link. There is also a link to the 2010 Beta program on there. This should be enough to get you started as there is plenty of information about Sharepoint development on the Web

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to go for [online video tutorials for sharepoint](http://www.bestdotnettraining.com/online-sharepoint-2013-training) rather than document study. It will surely save your time. You won't need any other reference after watching some good SharePoint video.

Comment: If you want to provide only reference link then you should have to provide it in comment because only reference links are not welcome on SO