# SharePoint Site Administration Training

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, administration

I've never used SharePoint, but my SharePoint Site Admin just rolled off of our team and my Manager asked me if I could take over her role. We run **MS Office 2013** (including InfoPath) but consult for teams that use a **variety of SharePoint servers - namely 2007**.

My management is willing to pay for SharePoint training - on top of just taking over the admin roll they want to overhaul the site.

I'm curious if I should go for **training in SharePoint 2007 or 2013 (or others) and why** that recommendation. I want the training to give me a functional capability but also have longevity.

Note:-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
I looked here:
[Sharepoint Training](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1785616/sharepoint-training) and may look into the development side as well, but for now I'm primarily interested in the administrative side, best practices, and capabilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good to see u r developing interest in Sharepoint.. :)

Regarding your query about training.. As a part of your job if you have to handle Sharepoint 2007 a.k.a. Moss portals, Its my recommendetation that you go for 2007 training.

**Why 2007 not 2013?**

Sharepoint has come long way since 2007 - 2013. So there are so many changes in terms of Architecture, UI, Sharepoint development, Capacity and third party tool integration.

To cut the long story short.. If you have to handle 2007 portals better go for 2007 training.. But once you understand achitecture, Start exploring 2013 as well.. Good luck :)

Comment: @Vaibahv, thank you for your feedback. I wasn't sure if studying 2013 would intuitively help me understand 2007 or if the advances were significant enough that I needed to use 2007 as the foundation - and it sounds like I do.

In your experience, is it possible to be a "SharePoint Site Administrator" without the development capability or are the two skill sets intertwined? If I need both in my arsenal which would you recommend learning first - the development or the admin sides?

Thanks again for your input!
-E

Comment: Its always good to know everything :) but i would recommend you to be 'SP Admin' first.. You need to understand how sharepoint works before you start thinking in terms of coding perspective.. Sharepoint has invented its own terminology.. it will take some time for you to grab those words & their 'Real' meanings. Once you understand sharepoint as product, you can become better developer :)